# Add data to nested json file on server using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Ive searched alot on internet but havent found the answer to my Q, im new to using JSON and i have a hard time trying to figure out how i can add some nodes to an existing json file on my server. (Im able to post data but they allways end up at the end of the json file and not in the nested structure of the file.)

this is my code

```
var newUser = [{
                user: [{
                    id: username,
                    pw: password,
                    name: "user3",
                    icons: [{
                        bookmarks: "bookmark3",
                        notes: "note3"
                    }]
                }]
        }];

    var userSetup = JSON.stringify(newUser);

    var info = $('#info');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: themeUrl + '/json/user.json',
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data){
            var webdeskUserData = $.parseJSON(data);



            $.each(webdeskUserData.users, function() {
                $.each(this.userID1, function() {
                    info.append(this.id + this.name);
                    $.each(this.icons, function() {
                        info.append(this.bookmarks);
                    });
                });
            });
            // Tried doing it like this
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: themeUrl + '/script.php',
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                data: { 
                    data: userSetup
                }
            });
            // Or like this
                            webdeskUserData.users.push(userSetup);
        }
    });
```

I can read the file, im just not able to add new nodes to it. Can i do this with jQuery? I hope someone can tell me what im doing wrong.

Comment: jQuery/JavaScript only works on the clientside, you cannot add data to your files on the server with it. In this instance, your script.php should do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any chance you can give me an example? my script.php is very simple atm.

Comment: I don't know php, add a php tag to your question and also [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+process+json+with+php)